# MySQL join and group based on date ranges

Tags: mysql, join

I have table `A`

```
uid    dt         val_A
10     04/09/2012   34
10     08/09/2012   35
10     10/09/2012   36
100    04/09/2012   40
100    08/09/2012   41
```

and table `B`

```
uid   date        val_B
10    04/09/2012    1
10    05/09/2012    1
10    06/09/2012    2
10    07/09/2012    2
10    08/09/2012    1
100   07/09/2012    1
100   07/09/2012    3
```

I want to join them to get table `C`. I want to join them on `uid`. Furthermore I want to have a new column `val_C` which holds the average of `val_B` where date in `B` is greater or equal than the corresponding row-value `dt` in `A` AND less than the next higher `dt` value for this `uid` in table `A`. It means I want to aggregate the values in `B` based on date ranges defined in `A`. The joined table should look like this:

```
uid    dt         val_A    val_C
10     04/09/2012   34     1.5
10     08/09/2012   35     1
10     10/09/2012   36     0
100    04/09/2012   40     2
100    08/09/2012   41     0
```

How can this be achieved?

//EDIT
How could a more generalized solution look like where all dates in `B2` which are greater than the greatest date in `A` are being joined & aggregated to the greatest date in `A`. `B2`:

```
uid   date        val_B
10    04/09/2012    1
10    05/09/2012    1
10    06/09/2012    2
10    07/09/2012    2
10    08/09/2012    1
100   07/09/2012    1
100   07/09/2012    3
100   10/09/2012    4
100   11/09/2012    2
```

Desired output `C2`:

```
uid    dt         val_A    val_C
10     04/09/2012   34     1.5
10     08/09/2012   35     1
10     10/09/2012   36     0
100    04/09/2012   40     2
100    08/09/2012   41     3
```

Comment: The date `08/09/2012` for `uid=100` doesn't exists in both of you table data example, where is it from? And what is you MySQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on MySQL v8+ that supports `LEAD()` function, then you can try this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT uid, dt, val_A,
       IFNULL(LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY uid, dt),dt) dtRg
FROM tableA)
SELECT cte.uid, cte.dt, cte.val_A,
       AVG(val_B) AS val_C
  FROM cte
LEFT JOIN tableB tb1
 ON cte.uid=tb1.uid
AND tb1.dt >= cte.dt
AND tb1.dt < cte.dtRg
GROUP BY cte.uid, cte.dt, cte.val_A
```

The query in common table expression (`cte`):

```
  SELECT uid, dt, val_A,
       IFNULL(LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY uid, dt),dt) dtRg
FROM tableA
```

will give you a result like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `dtRg` column is generated using `LEAD()` function which takes the next row `dt` value according to the `ORDER BY`. Read more about [LEAD() here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead).

After that, join the `cte` with `tableB` on matching `uid` and where `tableB.dt` is the same or bigger than the existing `tableA.dt` - *which is now as `cte.dt`*, but lower than `cte.dtRg` - *which is the next date in `tableA` that was generated by `LEAD()`*. And finally adding `AVG(val_B) AS val_C`

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5dMKGI3w)

On older MySQL version, you can try this:

```
SELECT tA.uid, tA.dt, tA.val_A,
       AVG(val_B) AS val_C
   FROM 
(SELECT uid, dt, val_A,
       (SELECT dt FROM tableA ta1 
         WHERE ta1.uid=ta2.uid 
          AND ta1.dt > ta2.dt LIMIT 1) AS dtRg
  FROM tableA ta2) tA
LEFT JOIN tableB tB 
  ON tA.uid=tB.uid
AND tB.dt >= tA.dt
AND tB.dt < tA.dtRg
GROUP BY tA.uid, tA.dt, tA.val_A;
```

The difference are as following:

1. Instead of using `LEAD()`, it uses correlated subquery in `SELECT` to get the next `dt` value of next row in the same `uid`.
2. Instead of common table expression, it uses a derived table.

[Fiddle for MySQL v5.7 version](https://dbfiddle.uk/1EyuuzRE)

Comment: I really like your solution with lead(). However it does not work anymore correctly if the most recent date in `B` is more recent than the most recent date in `A`. Because for the last row in `A` it creates `dtRg` which is equal to `dt`. Ideally `dtRg` for the last row would be in the infinite future. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you provide the data sample for the scenario?

Comment: I updated the initial post accordingly.

Comment: Maybe like this @volfi , https://dbfiddle.uk/diPnhfNo .