# Transform correlated subquery to be used with presto / athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a mysql query which contains a correlated subquery. This is not supported within presto which is why I am looking for a way to have the same functionality in ansi sql syntax. The query (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75469004/mysql-join-and-group-based-on-date-ranges) post) is as follows:

```
SELECT tA.uid, tA.dt, tA.val_A,
       AVG(val_B) AS val_C
   FROM 
(SELECT uid, dt, val_A,
       (SELECT dt FROM tableA ta1 
         WHERE ta1.uid=ta2.uid 
          AND ta1.dt > ta2.dt LIMIT 1) AS dtRg
  FROM tableA ta2) tA
LEFT JOIN tableB tB 
  ON tA.uid=tB.uid
AND tB.dt >= tA.dt
AND tB.dt < tA.dtRg
GROUP BY tA.uid, tA.dt, tA.val_A;
```

If I run the query in the presto db it throws following error message:

```
[Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 5:9: Given correlated subquery is not supported [Execution ID: 60a6f7e2-fb2b-44e0-a4f2-847ac669e905]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with `>=` logic and/or `dt`'s are unique within the same `uid` you can leverage window functions:

```sql
(SELECT uid,
        dt,
        val_A,
        lead(dt) over (partition by uid order by dt) AS dtRg
FROM tableA ta2) tA
```

Otherwise I'm afraid you are limited to performing join and selecting first result from it - for expiration check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69809806/2501279) (or using `row_number` window function).